# What´s wrong in this computation of $\Delta(r^{-1})$ as a distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory

maybe this is an idiot question, but I could not figure out what´s wrong. I know how to compute $\Delta (r^{-1})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ putting a ball with center in $0$ and then get $\Delta(r^{-1}) = -4 \pi \delta$, however I tried to compute it in other way and I got $\Delta(r^{-1}) =0$.

If $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, then, choosing $\Omega$ such that $supp(\phi) \subset \Omega$ and $\partial \Omega \cap supp{\phi} = \emptyset$, $\langle\Delta(r^{-1}), \phi \rangle = \langle r^{-1}, \Delta\phi \rangle = \int_\Omega r^{-1} \Delta \phi = \int_\Omega \Delta(r^{-1})\phi - \int_{\partial\Omega} r^{-1}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial n}  + \int_{\partial\Omega} \phi\frac{\partial\ r^{-1}}{\partial n} = 0 $ since the first integral is zero because $\Delta (r^{-1}) = 0$  in $\mathbb{R}^{3} \setminus \{0\}$, and the last two integrals vanish because $supp(\Delta\phi) \subset supp(\phi)$ and $supp(\phi) \cap \partial\Omega = \emptyset$. What´s wrong here??!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it necessary for Green's identity that $r$ is twice differentiable in *all* of $\Omega$? That precisely the reason for the ball around $0$ as far as I remember.

Comment: @Vobo Yes, twice continuously differentiable, because of the laplacian (it must be integrable). I don't know if this is exactly the problem, since the laplacian will vanish everywhere except at $0$, so it's just a set of null measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the laplacian will vanish everywhere except at $0$, so it's just a set of null measure.

Sets of measure zero may be negligible for integration   of *functions* but they are *not* negligible for application of the  Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, or of its higher dimensional forms (Green, Stokes, etc). They are not negligible for working with  *distributions*, either.

Consider a simpler example: 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad &\text{if }\ x\ge 0, \\ 0\quad &\text{if }\ x<0\end{cases}$$
Following your logic, one could say that 
$$  f(1)-f(-1) = \int_{-1}^1 f'(x)\,dx = 0 \tag{1}$$
because $f'(x)=0$ except at one point. Clearly, something is wrong here because $f(1)-f(-1)=1$.

There are two ways to resolve the issue:

1. Say that the first step is invalid, because the fundamental theorem of calculus does not apply to $f$.
2. Extend the notion of derivative to "distributional  derivative". Then the first step in (1) is correct, but the second is not: $f'$ is the distribution supported at one point, namely the Dirac delta. The integral of $f'$ over $[-1,1]$ is $1$.

The same options apply to your problem. Either Green's identity is understood in the sense of classical derivatives (and then it's  not applicable to $r^{-1}$ on a domain that includes $0$), or it is understood in the sense of distributions, and then the integral involving $\Delta(r^{-1})$ is nonzero: it's not really an integral, but evaluation of the distribution $\Delta(r^{-1})$ on the test function $\phi$. The latter option is not helpful either (it's basically a tautology), if your goal is to find $\Delta(r^{-1})$.

So, what one usually does for evaluation of $\Delta(r^{-1})$ is to apply the classical Green's identity on a domain that does not include $0$ (not even on the boundary). Namely, on the complement of $B(0,\epsilon)$ in the domain.

Comment: Yes, that is what I remembered calculating the fundamental solution of the Laplacian.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't notice it.